# how to pass laravel queue with select query and render the data in view

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-queue

How can i use queue in Laravel 5.4 to select query and then render the data whene data is ready.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the following:

1. Add the job to the queue
2. Redirect to another page (or stay where you are if it's client-scripted)
3. Watch if the task is done with Ajax. Just fetch for the data you need. If it's there - it's done. If not yet - try again in some period of time, like a few seconds.
4. Once it's there, refresh your GUI with JavaScript.

Comment: Okey, and how should I do the third and fourth part? Im not  good in JS and AJAX... How to use this data from queue and send it to AJAX?

Comment: You don't use the data from the queue per se. Create an endpoint that would check, for example, if particular record exists in the database or not. I shouldn't write tutorial of JS and Ajax here, read some.

Comment: I have a new idea with VueJS, do uyou know that technology and can help me ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45338077/how-to-store-data-in-vuejs-with-laravel-5-4