# How to store data in VueJS with Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-5.4, laravel-queue

Im building application like real time dashboard. Using many databases and external APIs.

(The first Idea was AJAX + Laravel Queues, but I found VueJS and It's interesting.)

The idea is to get the data in background with Laravel Queues from all sources and then storage it localy. Next step is getting this data with VueJS.

The problem I have is the storage part. I dont have idea and actually dont know how to store it so VueJS can efficiently get this data from storage and on the other hand Laravel can save the data to it the same.

There will be many users loging in a system so I created the MySQL database for them but dont know, if it's a good solution.

Thanks for advices!

Comment: Vue doesn't need to be aware of how your backend (Laravel) fetches and stores data from external sources as long as you build an API that you can call from the client (Vue or other) to fetch "local" data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You create routes for Vue.js to make XHR(Ajax) requests to. If you want to save data this would be a `post` route. If you want to retrieve data this would be a `get` route.

How you handle the data you are sending or (directly)receiving is of no concern to Vue.js.

This would be a good start:

https://laracasts.com/series/learn-vue-2-step-by-step/episodes/18